Recent machine learning/AI by-for physicists
I am looking for a recent (no more than 6 months or so in arXiv) review of machine and/or deep learning developments for physicist written by physicists, preferably with material and discussions about AI.

It's funny that the question is being closed because of opinion based, since in the definition of that case we read "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations", and what I am asking for is precisely a citation, not an opinion.

I don’t see how this question is different to any reference/book request question and thus do not believe that it should have been closed.

@ThomasTappeiner Agreed, I have voted to reopen.

Seems to me that if you have a specific subject, a certain timeline (<=6M old) and indicated a location (arXiv), you should be able to conclude your search. I don't understand why you've posted here when this is effectively a 'lmgtfy' type question

@KyleKanos some people may have lecture notes or similar reviews that might not necessarily be published in arXiv. I mentioned the site just as an example. My main concern is that the reference is made from a physics stand point.

And you can't use a search engine for that because...
